# Is it possible to find an element like a button and click it, when it is continuously moving on? e.g Carousel

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am using Selenium Webdriver(Ruby) to automate my web app and my web app has this carousel wherein my element continuously keeps moving in a loop.
By the time I locate that element and try to click it, element moves ahead.Hence I am not able to locate that element.
I tried finding and clicking that moving element by following code:

```
    {
    ele_button = driver.find_element(:xpath,"xpath")
    sleep 10
    ele_button.click
    }
```

I thought that by 'sleep 10' I could make that element wait for 10 seconds and then click it.But this does not work and I am getting ElementNotVisibleError whenever I run my script.

Question:

Is it even possible to automate a moving element? If yes please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is absolutely possible. I handled same scenario for carousel on my site. There are three ways:

- Most carousel stop on mouse hover. So you may use it to stop the
  carousel. Use Actions class to move over to the carousel. Once it
  stops you may click on it.
- If you want a specific slide, you can click on **dots** or any other navigator, like prev/nxt, to reach your slide and then click it.
- The sure shot way to click your specific slide, without worrying about whether it is displayed or not is to use Javascript to click it (Which I had done in my case although I had also implemented 2nd way but I found javascript the simplest solution).

Comment: I tried the same by clicking one of the hotspot(dot) and then providing sleep for few seconds and then clicking the button in order to play a video.But my carousel keeps moving like every 5 seconds and so I am not able to find the button and click it.It returns ElementNotVisibleError whenever I run the script.

Comment: What about javascript??

Comment: I have no idea about javascript...I am using Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Why are the actions divided?

I would recommend the following:

```
driver.find_element(:xpath,"xpath").click()
```

so it will find the object and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do, as we doing in selenium with java that put the **implicitlyWait** according to the time on which your button came back after **one rotation**; now perform click just after implicitlyWait

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Suppose a rotation of button takes 30 sec

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]")).click();
// action performs on the element
```

In **ruby** you have to use this type of syntax

```
@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
```